# Setting Up Postman for API Testing When Using user Authorization in hmvc codeigniter

Tags: api, codeigniter, hmvc

I am new to restful api. So I am trying to test a project to learn about api. Demo project path is: 
    https://github.com/devangnaghera312/ci-rest-structure
I am writing the link "http://localhost/ci-rest-structure-master/v1/user?fname=Devang&lname=naghera"  in postman(post method) to get user access, but it shows that access token is missing. 
 Would you please tell me why this error is occuring and how to get access to the api? Thanks in advance for your effort.

I have followed some youtube videos such as 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibEs4g1jGyc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2i-rt0yxDQ&t=735s
  but in vain!

Comment: None has time to help me in this issue!!

Comment: Maybe this is a silly issue! But sometimes a little issue is the biggest hindrance to a complete project!